# What's the meaning of "=>" when not calling a function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm learning JavaScript through freeCodeCamp and the way they explained (or rather, didn't) arrow functions has led to some massive confusion for me.

I am familiar with calling a function using arrow notation like this:

```
const myFunc = () => "value";
```

But in one of the later challenges, the code they provided calls a function I have to write using the following code:

```
findElement([1, 2, 3, 4], num => num % 2 === 0);
```

Here, the arrow notation is used as a parameter for a function, and not when calling a function. I have no idea what it means.

I managed to write a function that works:

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  let num;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    num = arr[i];
    console.log(num);
    if (func(num)) {
      return num; 
    } 
  }
}
```

but I don't understand *why* it works

Comment: They're both the same. `() => "value"` isn't calling a function, it's _defining_ one. So is `num => num % 2 === 0`. The only difference is assigning to a variable, rather than passing as a parameter.

Comment: `const myFunc = () => "value";` doesn't call the function, it declares one and is equivalent (in this case) to `const myFunc = function() { return "value"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [`=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is an arrow function - a shorter version of writing a normal function, but with some gotchas.

In your following code, the `()` is necessary because the function is taking no parameters...

```
const myFunc = () => "value";
console.log(myFunc()); // Results in "value"
```

If you had one parameter, then you can lose the brackets (although you don't have to)... both the following are both valid...

```
const myFunc = myArg => "value " + myArg;
const myFunc = (myArg) => "value " + myArg;
console.log(myFunc("a")); // Result in "value a";
```

If you had two or more parameters, then you also need the brackets...

```
const myFunc = (myArg1, myArg2) => "value";
const myFunc = (myArg1, myArg2, myArg3) => "value";
```

As a result in the following code, you are creating an arrow function with a single parameter (`num`) and so it doesn't need the brackets (these are identical)...

```
findElement([1, 2, 3, 4], num => num % 2 === 0);
findElement([1, 2, 3, 4], (num) => num % 2 === 0);
```

The *gotchas* I mentioned earlier are to do with binding to keywords like `this`, `arguments` and `super`... [which you can read more about in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!

I've been losing my mind over what it could mean without the parentheses

now I still don't know WHY would you ever drop the parentheses if it only applies to functions with single variables and creates immeasurable confusion but hey, JavaScript is wonderful and not at all confusing! :P

Comment: @szymonhimself - you're very welcome - good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 1):

`=>` is the arrow function expressions.

It is a compact alternative to a traditional function expression.

You can find out more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

For example, the following function definition:

```
let f = function(arg1, arg2, ...) {
  return true;
};
```

can be shortened with the `=>`:

```
let f = (arg1, arg2, ...) => true;
```